# Php download from hashed pathfile

Tags: php, html, mime, fileinfo

I'm having trouble with downloading a file from a hashed filepath.

I'm using a MySQL database where I store various data from a HTML form. It is possible to upload up to three different files. These are moved to a uploads folder on the server. I’m using MD5 to prevent duplicate file uploads.

All the data in the database gets called from an other script. There is an amount of download links shown, depending on how much files are uploaded. Im using fileinfo and headers to determine the mimetype and to download the file. But all I get when downloading is some zipfile with random folders and documents or a non-extension file which, giving the right extension, opens with warnings and ultimately shows the correct file.

Here is my download code:

```
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
    print("</br>"); echo finfo_file($finfo, $_GET["fName"]);

    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= ". $_GET["fName"]);
    header("Content-Type: " .$finfo);
    finfo_close($finfo);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

     // Read the file from disk
         readfile($_GET["fName"]);
```

The `$_GET["fName"]` is a variable passed by a link which contains the specified pathname(example: `./uploads/hashcode`). How can I make this so that I can download the document correctly? As in download the document whole, not some ZIP file or a non-extension file.

I’ve been fighting with this problem for some days now (searched on internet to find something usable) and im getting quite desperate.

Additional note: Most times the file that downloads is the correct file from my server. It has the same name as the hash files in the uploads folder. But it doesnt have any extension.

Comment: You are setting the name for downloaded file here 

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= ". $_GET["fName"]);

maybe you could use basename or some other function to get your file named properly

Comment: Also this isn't very secure. If someone called script.php?fName=script.php or anything else, they would be able to download your configurations files and everything saved on your server,

Comment: I know it's not one of the safest ways. I just want to get this download problem done before I go in security mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say $_GET["fName"] is /uploads/randomhash/ABCDEFABCDEFABCDEF.zip

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= ". basename($_GET["fName"]));
```

This would make the server to name downloadable file as ABCDEFABCDEFABCDEF.zip

If you have saved your files without extension, then you might have a problem.
If you have the orginal filename saved in database maybe you could add extra $_GET['orginalFilename'] to your links and use that to generate right filename with extension.

Also you are setting headers. They aren't being set correctly if you output anything before them. Here you print  and finfo_file. You shouldn't do that.

I think you want something like this, but you have to figure out how to get right filename to the filename= part in header.

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= ". basename($_GET["fName"]));
header("Content-Type: " . finfo_file($finfo, $_GET["fName"]));
finfo_close($finfo);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");*/

 // Read the file from disk
 readfile($_GET["fName"]);
```

Comment: Allright, I'll change the headers. But how can I change the "Content-type" to the correct mime if its above the finfo_open? Thanks for the help. I'm quite new with fileinfo and mimes.

Comment: You can use finfo_open you just can't echo finfo_file($finfo, $_GET["fName"]);

Comment: Allrighty then. The echo was more used for testing reasons. Forgot to remove it. Thanks for pointing that out though.